# Change Pandas JSON output structure

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame, that after applying a `groupby` function

```
df.groupby(['USER', 'GROUP'])['VALOR'].sum()
```

outputs this:

```
USER               GROUP
John Doe           A        201.37
                   B        480.59
                   C       1504.16
John Jones         A        239.95
                   B       1123.39
                   C       1736.05
...
```

However, when I convert this `df` to JSON:

```
df.to_json()
```

It returns this:

```
{"["John Doe","A"]":201.37,"["John Doe","B"]":480.59,"["John Doe","C"]":1504.16", "["John Jones","A"]":239.95,"["John Jones","B"]":1123.39,"["John Jones","C"]":1736.05}
```

Is there a way to output it in this format:

```
{"John Doe": {"A": 201.37, "B":480.59, "C":1504.16}, "John Jones": {"A": 239.95, "B":1123.39, "C":1736.05}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `unstack` it first.

```
df.unstack(0).to_json()
```

```
{
    "John Doe": {
        "A": 201.37,
        "B": 480.59,
        "C": 1504.16
    },
    "John Jones": {
        "A": 239.95,
        "B": 1123.39,
        "C": 1736.05
    }
}
```